# Magento 1.9 Soap: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [100] Requested order not exists

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap-api-v1

I try to get data from `sales_order.info`.

I connect via $_POST data, where I need to input the order number in a form. When I input a wrong order invalid order number I get a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [100] Requested order not exists.

How can I modify my code, that instead of fatal error I get my message ("order number not correct, pls try again")

```
$orderresult = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.info', ''.$_POST["ordernumber"].'');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code inside a `try {} catch($e) {}` block.

So:

```
try {
    $orderresult = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.info', ''.$_POST["ordernumber"].'');
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: getting a parse error now:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$e' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or namespace (T_NAMESPACE) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)**

Comment: Made an adjustment; I added an exception identifier.